How can I add multiple query parameters with the same name but different values with Saloon (PHP)?
I integrated a remote API with my PHP web application using Saloon. I usually set my query parameter on my Request like this:
$this->query()->set([
  'param1' => 'val1',
  'param2' => 'val2',
  'param3' => ['val3', 'val4']
]);

This works perfectly and I get the expected URL/?param1=val1&param2=val2&param3[]=val3&param3[]=val4.
But now I'm dealing with a remote endpoint that expects multiple parameters with the same name and different values, as in /?param1=val1&param2=val2&param3=val3&param3=val4, How can I obtain this with Saloon?

There are some solutions in this question do they apply to your case?

hi @barmar thanks for your reply. Yes, it's the same problem, but I don't know how to access the Guzzle instance from my Saloon request before the request is sent

My solution was to manually build the endpoint URL directly, so that my resolveEndpoint() returns the full URL /?param1=val1&param2=val2&param3=val3&param3=val4.
It's definitely not the prettiest solution ever, but it gets the job done.
